# Prevent AngularJS interpolation in certain DOM hierarchies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I use AngularJS and have some parts of HTML that I don't wish to interpolate because it contains user inputted data. So potentially the data may have `{{asdf}}` in there that I don't want AngularJS to parse. This is because if the user inputs `{{{}, {}}` this may break the compilation process and prevent any Angular code from running.

Is there a way around this by specifying to Angular not to compile this part of the DOM tree?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[The Non Bindable directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngNonBindable) I believe is what your looking for.

So at any element you can do:

```
<div ng-non-bindable> Some {{1+2}} expressions</div>
```

That will display:

```
Some {{1+2}} expressions
```

Comment: Is there a way to show a `{{` without being compiled by Angular? e.g. escaping it with a `\\`?

Comment: I haven't tried, but maybe using the HTML charater codes?  `&#123;` is `{`.  `&#125;` => `}`

Comment: Yes, you can use backslashes to escape the `{{`, e.g. `\{\{ username = "defaced value"; \}\}` (example from the Angular docs to be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate)